# Meaning of "There is a part of me"

Tags: american-english

**Sentence**
There is a part of me that even likes this guy, It's a part of me, I hate. but it is a part of me,

Question: What is the meaning of "There is a part of me"

Source: https://youtu.be/DnpO_RTSNmQ?t=88

Answer (score 1):

What it means is

> Although I do not like him, I like some things about him. That I like any aspect of him indicates that some of my own aspects do not meet my ideals, but I cannot deny that those aspects of myself exist.

It is a metaphor pretending that the speaker is a group of distinct individuals, and a minority of them like this guy whom we are discussing. The majority are ashamed of that minority, but cannot deny that they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The author of this passage believes (like many people do) that human beings are composed of parts. Not just physical body parts, like your legs, and head, etc., but your personality and psyche are also made up of parts.

So the author is saying that some parts of his own personality have different feelings than other parts. Some part of his personality "*even likes this guy*".

It seems to be a minor part, because he says he *hates* that part of himself. It sounds like the majority of his personality doesn't "like this guy", but there is one small part which disagrees.